# Multiple arrays to CSV

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, scripting

I have multiple arrays and trying to write them to a CSV file.

I'm trying to achieve the following results:

```
20,2,1,00:12:34:56:78:90,3,1000,1000,name
```

Above is a single line as example, but expect 64x such lines on CSV file.
1st value is index number, 2nd value is fixed number, 3rd value is fixed number, 4th value is Mac address from array, 5th, 6th and 7th values are from array.

The following code does not work:

```
echo $write1count,2,1,${macaddress[recallcount]},${antconf[recallcount]},${ulmir[recallcount]},$dlmir{recallcount]},${nameconf[recallcount]} >>$filename
```

Above gives follow result:

```
,devicename
```

Effectively it seems the last array entry (nameconf) is overwriting everything specified before it.

I also tried using

> printf

but as soon as I introduce an array value, does it overwrite previous values in the same line

Any guidance?

Comment: Remove the MSWin line ends from the input.

Comment: @Clint : I don't know what you mean by `result`. `filename` will contain at least several comma. You did not specify **how** you checked the content of `filename`. Did you do a `xxd filename` or `od -cx filename?`?

Comment: Hi Choroba. Indeed....that fixed it. Each array value I captured before, had a newline at the end. Every value I captured was read from another csv file and it was always the last entry in the line.